# Pegar nome da fonte no .bat

Tags: batch, font

Estou usando o *script* abaixo para instalar fontes no Windows, porém gostaria de saber se existe como pegar o nome da *face* da fonte. Por exemplo, o nome do arquivo da fonte é `BebasNeue.otf`, mas o nome da face dela é `Bebas Neue (OpenType)`. Como pegar o nome da *face* por *script* para registrar corretamente?

O script está gravando o nome da fonte BebasNeue no registro e gostaria que ele gravasse o nome da face no caso Bebas Neue (OpenType).

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

echo instalando fontes....

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b \\mulinfsv0005\Configs\fonts\') do (
    set variable=%%f
    set variable=!variable:~0,-4!
    echo !variable!
    xcopy \\servidorOrigem\Configs\fonts\%%f c:\Windows\Fonts /y /q
    reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /v !variable! /t REG_SZ /d %%f /f
) 
endlocal

echo As fontes foram instaladas!

pause
```

Comment: Parece que para fazer isto pode se usar o PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução, **mas** que não envolve só batch é utilizar um programa para extrair o nome da fonte diretamente do arquivo. Isso pode ser feito com várias linguagens (C, Python e etc). Não sei se existe alguma forma com batch puro que resolva isso.

---

**Exemplo:**

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [freetype](http://www.freetype.org/) para carregar a fonte e obter o nome. Para isso, você pode utilizar o seguinte código (em C):

```
#include <stdint.h>

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

#include <freetype.h>
#include <ftglyph.h>
#include <ftsnames.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Verifica se há parâmetros:
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Nenhum parametro informado.");
        return 0;
    }

    // O arquivo da fonte que se extrairá o nome.
    const char* face_target = argv[1];

    FT_Library  library;

    int error = FT_Init_FreeType(&library);
    if (error)
    {
        // Erro ao carregar biblioteca.
        return -1;
    }

    FT_Face face;
    error = FT_New_Face(library, face_target, 0, &face);

    if (error == FT_Err_Unknown_File_Format)
    {
        // Erro: Provavelmente o arquivo da fonte não é suportado.
        return -1;
    }
    else if (error)
    {
        // Erro: Não foi possível abrir o arquivo ou o arquivo está quebrado.
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        // A fonte foi lida com sucesso:

        FT_SfntName name;
        memset(&name, 0, sizeof(FT_SfntName));
        FT_Get_Sfnt_Name(face, 1, &name);

        printf("%.*s", name.string_len, name.string);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

E gerar um programa que imprime o nome da fonte, dado o arquivo dela. Supondo que o programa seja nomeado como "font2name" e esteja acessível, você pode chamá-lo em Batch assim:

```
font2name BebasNeue.otf > name.txt
set /p FACE_NAME=< name.txt
echo %FACE_NAME%
```

Com isso, FACE_NAME armazenará o nome da fonte do jeito que você quer "Bebas Neue".

---

Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que o mesmo pode ser feito com python, utilizando [o freetype para python](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-py). Mas, eu não sei se, para o que você está fazendo, é possível substituir o batch por python.

Comment: Na verdade preciso de um script para instalar +150 fontes por gpo, tenho um script em PowerShell que instala fonte por fonte fazendo o registro automático das fontes.(não testei ainda na gpo), mas, gostei da sua solução, vou ver se acho essa biblioteca para c#.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no https://github.com/Robmaister/SharpFont. É uma implementação do FreeType para C#, não deve mudar muito em comparação com o código que mostrei.

Comment: Hum, Interresante, vou dar uma conferida. Obrigado!